# How, from a list of points, do I find available free area (rectangles)

Tags: c#, algorithm

We deliver a control system that comprise modules laid across a huge 2D coordinate system.

I need an algorithm that can locate available spaces whose dimensions are at least a minimum height and width. "Available" means "not containing any points in the list".
It would also be advantageous if the algorithm could accept a list of rectangles that should not intersect with any rectangles returned by the algorithm.

I have tried the following algorithm, but it doesn't feel right.

- Chose a candidate point that is not in a previously returned candidate rectangle or previously dismissed area.
- Grow horizontally until minimum width is reached.
- Grow vertically until minimum height is reached.
- At this point, this is an approved candidate rectangle, but could still be bigger.
- Grow horizontally as far as possible.
- Grow vertically as far as possible.
- Return rectangle as approved. (If points 2 or 3 fails, the area covered thus far is dismissed.

Are there any bright heads out there that can suggest a better algorithm for this?
(EDIT: note that the rectangles are axis aligned)

Comment: This does not seem to be a simple task, as your rectangle set can be of infinite possibilities. Also if those rectangles of yours are not axis-aligned, things go even more difficult.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the rectangles are axis aligned.

Comment: When you say huge 2D coordinate system, do you mean that the point coordinates have high magnitudes or that there is a very large number of points?

Comment: I have no solution to this problem, but I would propably start by checking if i can achieve something like this with a Quadtree or Kd-tree. I would start to check cells, and neighbouring cells and would try to develope something out of the relation between the cells. Again this is just the first thing that came to my mind how i would first try to solve this.

Comment: Also: in a case where you could either fit one large rectangle or multiple minimum size rectangles (whose combined area is larger than your large rectangle for the same area), which is preferable?

Comment: @DanBryant I mean that the both axis have -64K to +64K scale and that the number of "occupied" points are considerable, so that the algorithm must scale. For example, an algorithm that used every point to "split" an existing rectangle into four new candidate rectangles would not work due to n square problems.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_rectangle) gives you something to further research into.

Comment: @DanBryant I would rather have one large rectangle returned rather than multiple minimum sized ones. Even if the larger rectangle would prevent "creative use" of smaller rectangles. The point is that the area has been pointed out to the users, who can take it from there.

Comment: 1- List all empty areas within the image. 2- For every empty area, find best fitting rectangle. 3- Select the best rectangle given your preference.

Comment: How many points do you have at most?

Comment: @aram90 Depends on the system, of course. A regular system will have about 50-100K points. A larger system will have about 2-3M.